# Query alias issue

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
`tblTrainingSessionProgramming`.`trainingSessionProgramID`, `tblExercises`.`exerciseName`, `tblRepSchemes`.`repScheme`
FROM 
`tblExercises` , `tblRepSchemes`
LEFT JOIN 
`tblTrainingSessionProgramming` ON `tblExercises`.`exerciseID` = `tblTrainingSessionProgramming`.`exerciseID` 
LEFT JOIN 
`tblTrainingSessionProgramming` ON `tblRepSchemes`.`repSchemeID` = `tblTrainingSessionProgramming`.`repSchemeID`
```

I am trying to run this query but get error

> 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'tblTrainingSessionProgramming'

When I try to alias the table it then says that it can't find another database column. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
SELECT 
`TSP`.`trainingSessionProgramID`, `E`.`exerciseName`, `RS`.`repScheme`
FROM 
`tblExercises` E 
LEFT JOIN 
`tblTrainingSessionProgramming` TSP ON `E`.`exerciseID` = `TSP`.`exerciseID` 
LEFT JOIN 
`tblRepSchemes` RS ON `RS`.`repSchemeID` = `TSP`.`repSchemeID`
```

Answer (score 1):

You are joining the same table twice, give a unique alias for each join and use those alias when referencing columns. Also you need to join the table tblRepSchemes

Or you can use FROM tblTrainingSessionProgramming instead and join the other way

```
SELECT `tblTrainingSessionProgramming`.`trainingSessionProgramID`, `tblExercises`.`exerciseName`, `tblRepSchemes`.`repScheme`
FROM tblTrainingSessionProgramming 
JOIN `tblExercises ON `tblExercises`.`exerciseID` = `tblTrainingSessionProgramming`.`exerciseID` 
JOIN `tblRepSchemes` ON `tblRepSchemes`.`repSchemeID` = `tblTrainingSessionProgramming`.`repSchemeID`
```